# ComponentNotRegisteredException Probs - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

I recently upgraded a project I am working on to RC1 and I am absolute pulling my hair out. I am using AbsoluteRouting and I keep getting the following issue which is preventing me from upgrading. I have know cllue about whether you have any ideas but I thought I would see if you did (really appreciate any help you can provide :) )

After migrating I get this error:

Global.asax.cs

```
routes.Add(new EnableAbsoluteRouting()

               .SetPort("http", 2008)

               .SetPort("https", 450));



routes.Add(new Route("Login/SignIn", new MvcRouteHandler()) {

               Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Login", action         = "SignIn" })

        });
```

Control(*.ascx)  inside View

```
<% using (Html.Form<LoginController>(c => c.SignIn())) { %>



EnableAbsoluteRouting.cs:



    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext,     RouteValueDictionary values)

    {

        using (RouteTable.Routes.GetReadLock())

        {

            foreach (var routeBase in RouteTable.Routes)

            {

                if (routeBase != this)

                {

/// Error there:

                    var vpd = routeBase.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);

                    if (vpd != null)

                        return EnsureCorrectScheme(requestContext, routeBase, vpd);

                }

            }

        }

        return null;

    }
```

NullReferenceException:

"   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n

at System.Web.Routing.ParsedRoute.Bind(RouteValueDictionary currentValues, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteValueDictionary defaultValues,

RouteValueDictionary constraints)\r\n   at System.Web.Routing.Route.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext,

RouteValueDictionary values)\r\n   at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext,

RouteValueDictionary values)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Mvc.LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression[T](ViewContext context,

Expression`1 action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Mvc.LinkExtensions.BuildUrlFromExpression[T](HtmlHelper helper, Expression`1 action)\r\n

at Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcForm`1..ctor(HtmlHelper helper, HttpContextBase context, Expression`1 postAction, FormMethod method,

RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FormExtensions.Form[T](HtmlHelper helper, Expression`1 postAction,

FormMethod method, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FormExtensions.Form[T](HtmlHelper helper,

Expression`1 postAction)\r\n   at ASP.views_shared_controls_quicklogincontrol_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w,

Control parameterContainer) in

d:\ Projects\WebSite\Views\Shared\Controls\LoginControl.ascx:line 11\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)\r\n   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)\r\n   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)\r\n

at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)\r\n

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)"

---

Any ideas would really assist :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you upgraded to RC1 refresh?  This was a known bug and has since been fixed.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/30/aspnetmvc-refresh.aspx